# Upgrade expo from 49 -> 50 ["_interopRequireDefault is not a function js.hermes.engine"]

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting a TypeError: _interopRequireDefault error when upgrading my Expo SDK from 49 to 50. From what I know, this is related to the Babel compiler. I need some pointers on where to look for a solution. Has anyone had a similar error?

more information -> https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/27742

Im expecting upgrade to 50 sdk expo

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm getting the same error.